# При помощи php залогиниться на сайте

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть сайт. Часть данных на сайте скрыта и показывается только после авторизации. Логин и пароль для авторизации есть. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при помощи php залогиниться на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [cURL](http://htmlweb.ru/php/example/curl_login.php) для отправки POST-запроса на сервер.